# Selenium findElements throwing exception instead of returning empty list

Tags: java, selenium

According to my many answers all over SE, selenium's `driver.findElements()` should be returning an empty `List<WebElement>`when it can't locate any elements that match the criteria.  So why does this line:

```
items = driver.findElements(By.linkText("remove"))
```

throw an `ElementNotFoundException`? For context: this line is in a loop, it works fine several times before throwing this exception when there are no more "remove" links left.

In particular, [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14190/how-to-continue-script-when-element-is-not-found-in-selenium) is pretty explicit that this should give me an empty list.

**EDIT:**

Here's the whole loop that's causing the issue.

```
List<WebElement> items;
try {
    items = driver.findElements(CartPage.itemInCart);
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
    return;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
}

while (items.size() > 0) {
    List<WebElement> removeButtons = driver.findElements(CartPage.removeItem);
    removeButtons.get(0).click();
    click(CartPage.yesButton, "Confirm remove item");
    items = driver.findElements(CartPage.itemInCart);  // <--Exception here
}
```

Note the `try`/`catch` before the loop, that's what I was hoping to avoid using every single time I want to check is an element is visible.

Comment: What are you looping on?

Comment: @Tyler  Edited.  I'm trying to avoid using too many `try`s, it feels clunky.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe a bug? Could you share the stacktrace showing where in selenium the exception is thrown?

Comment: And can you clarify? What's the *exact* exception? There's an `ElementNotVisibleException` or a `NoSuchElementException` and a `NotFoundException` but no `ElementNotFoundException` that I can see in the current code base.

Answer (score 2):

The exception occurs because you have removed the last element from the cart and there is no more element left to be identified with the given criteria:

Say initially Items had 5 elements in it during WHILE LOOP until items.size() > 1 loop will work fine, but when items.size() ==1; it will enter the loop and execute but at

click(CartPage.yesButton, "Confirm remove item");

last element will be removed and no such element will exist hence causing an exception because locator "CartPage.itemInCart" value is not present in DOM anymore.

Comment: Right, but ain't it supposed to return an empty list if there are no elements?  From what I've read that's the main point of using `findElements` over `findElement`.

Comment: That is true if there are no elements present inside "CartPage.itemInCart" , but exception occurs when "CartPage.itemInCart" is not present itself